# How to input data into a defined function without changing code?

Tags: python, function

Hi I'm new to Python and have been learning independently. However, although seemingly simple I can't get past this problem.

So I'm creating a very simple chart whereby I enter a list of numbers and get corresponding pipes (|) to match.

```
def chart(list):
    for i in list:
        print('|' * i)
chart([2,7,1,4,2,3,9,3])
```

Gives output:

```
 ||
 |||||||
 |
 ||||
 ||
 |||
 |||||||||
 |||
```

However how would I do it so that the entered data "chart([2,7,1,4,2,3,9,3])" would not be done from the developed code itself? I tried:

```
def chart(list):
    for i in list:
        print('|' * i)
a = list(input("Enter List of nums: "))
chart([a]
```

But that error-ed? 
Any Solutions? Thanks for the help! (Ignore any indentation errors just typed it up without Python)

Comment: if you instruct the user to enter number separated by spaces, then you can call `chart(a.split())` on the input but you would need to typecast i to `int(i)`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: @Chris_Rands hmmm not sure? Had a look at it but still didn't really understand an explanation to why mine doesn't work?

Comment: @TheWickedest `input()` returns a string in Py 3, you want a list so if the user inputs `'1,2,3,4'` then use `a = [int(i) for i in input().split(',')]` (in python 2 use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`)

Comment: Ahh got it working @Chris_Rands Thanks!

Comment: `print '\n'.join(['|'*n for n in map( int , raw_input().strip().split() ) ])` . Enjoy learning python :) .

Answer (score 0):

How about using:

```
my_input = input("Enter List of nums: ")
input_list = [int(e) for e in my_input.split()]
```

The input looks like:

```
Enter List of nums: 1 2 3 4
```

and then pass the input_list to your function